# Ionic build ios is stuck

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, macos-sierra

I have trouble making a build in IOS, when I do a build in android not show any problema.No shows no mistake is only hung with the following message:

```
ionic build ios
Running command: /Users/kaos/Documents/Proyectos/Ionic/voxMonitor/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/kaos/Documents/Proyectos/Ionic/voxMonitor


add to body class: platform-ios

Building project: /Users/kaos/Documents/Proyectos/Ionic/voxMonitor/platforms/ios/voxMonitor.xcodeproj

    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator


2016-09-14 00:57:11.666 xcodebuild[81377:2780361] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

2016-09-14 00:57:11.668 xcodebuild[81377:2780361] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/OMQuickHelp.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

2016-09-14 00:57:11.669 xcodebuild[81377:2780361] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

Build settings from command line:

    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/kaos/Documents/Proyectos/Ionic/voxMonitor/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/kaos/Documents/Proyectos/Ionic/voxMonitor/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/kaos/Documents/Proyectos/Ionic/voxMonitor/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
    TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2
```

when I try to open the file xcodeproj, xcode does not start and waits indefinitely until the force exit.

My ionic info :

```
Your system information:

    Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
    Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
    Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
    ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
    ios-sim version: 5.0.8
    OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
    Node Version: v6.5.0
    Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

worth mentioning that I am currently using MacOS Sierra GM and Xcode 8 gm.

Edit : when creating a new project and replace the www directory with the version in my project, I can build ios, but once you modify any file no longer compile I can, being hung on the screen above.

Comment: I get this! Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Currently stuck at this as well.

Comment: Posted to the Ionic forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-build-ios-on-ionic-2/65911

Comment: Here the issue on Github https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1401

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin of the problem is the project folder is inside the Documents directory which in turn is synchronized to iCloud, so when you move the project to another directory that is not Documents or Desktop, you can build without problems. In this thread on github shows other users who managed to fix it this way.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1401#issuecomment-254989260

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps(And Before following these steps make sure you have installed **IOS SDK** on your system)

1. Remove Hooks with command `$ionic hooks remove`
2. Remove Platform with command `$ionic platform remove ios`
3. Now Add Hooks with command `$ionic hooks add`
4. Now add platform with command `$ionic platform ios`
5. Now create build with command `$ionic build ios`
6. Now Run your application with command `$ionic run ios`

Comment: if I have the SDK, follow the steps but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My case was the build would hang/stuck when running $ ionic cordova build ios. OS is MacOS Mojave.

My solution was to update ionic and cordova environment. Worth doing ionic cordova build ios --verbose to see what is happening during the build process.

```
$ brew link --overwrite ios-deploy
$ npm update -g native-run
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
$ npm install -g ionic-angular@latest
```

Config before update:

Ionic:

```
Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
@angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0
```

Cordova:

```
Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 23 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res : 0.9.0 
native-run  : 0.2.7 (update available: 0.3.0)
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/haule/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
ios-sim           : 8.0.2
NodeJS            : v10.19.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.19.0/bin/node)
npm               : 6.13.4
OS                : macOS Mojave
Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

Config after update:

Ionic:

```
Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
@angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0
```

Cordova:

```
Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 23 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res : 0.9.0
native-run  : 0.3.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/haule/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
ios-sim           : 8.0.2
NodeJS            : v10.19.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.19.0/bin/node)
npm               : 6.13.4
OS                : macOS Mojave
Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```